# How to show only a child with a specific value in it by filtering data from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm pretty new in the Android development universe. I'm working with Firebase right now.

I have a recyclerview that shows every offer with their Data. Now I want another recyclerview that only show the offers created by the user. I already added the userID to the offer. But I can not figure out, how to show only the orders with the userId of the current logged in user.

I can't find the right Firebase guide for that neither.

[image: Example of my Database]

Comment: This is basically filtering query from firebase database. Check out the official link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data. It can be achieved by using orderby column and equal to condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple query your data like this.

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("Offer").orderByChild("userID").equalTo("user id you want to fetch");
        query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                //TODO get the data here

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always customize you recyclerview adapter. Or have 2 different adapters, each for general offers and the one created by the user. While loading you can make two list and use appropriate adapter to render the offers.